# Unity GUITexture doesnt display correctly

Tags: unity-game-engine, guitexture

so i am making a game for android but the display window no matter what ratio i choose from the list the GUI textures never show same size as my phone or tablet so making things very hard to work out correct sizes and positions etc

is there anything i may be doing wrong or is this normal for GUI texturesin the display window?

i'm running a xperia 2 and a xperia z2 tablet in-case it is needed

Answer (score 0):

My limited research shows that the Xperia Z2 is 1920x1080.  So, in order to actually see the game view in the editor, you have to have a monitor that is bigger than 1920x1080 to display both the 1920x1080 game view plus the border.

If you happen to have a monitor with a resolution higher than 1920x1080, which is not common, then you can add your own 1920x1080 (Fixed Resolution) setting to the Editor and actually be able to increase the size of the window until the game view reaches 1920x1080.

[image]

Comment: ok thank you for now i am just building to the phone and also by adding some math to scale things to screen size everything is going well :)